# Django and Ajax refreshing a div

Tags: django, ajax

I am very new to JS/Ajax and a relative novice to Django. I am testing to see how I can get information back and forth from an Ajax call to my view, and back to Ajax to replace a header string as a simple test.

I can receive information back to my view (h1, which is "AJAX TEST"). What I can't seem to get is the h2text to change to "HEADER CHANGED".

Any help is appreciated as I don't know if it's my Django return function or my Ajax function.

Here is my ajax_test.html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="center">
        <h1 id="h1">AJAX TEST</h1>
        <div>
            <button id="btn">PRESS ME</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="update_div">
        {% include "ProdPlat/ajax_test_div.html" %}
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ProdPlat\js\ajax_test.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

My ajax_test_div.html (which I'm trying to refresh):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="center">
        <h2 id="h2">{{h2text.h2text}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My views_test.py:

```
def test_ajax(request):
    h2text = {'h2text': "INITIAL HEADER"}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger.debug('POST request')
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        logger.debug('text = {}'.format(text))
        h2text = "HEADER CHANGED"
        dict = {
            'h2text': h2text,
        }
        # return JsonResponse(dict)
        # return render(request, 'ProdPlat/ajax_test_div.html', {'h2text': h2text})
        return render_to_response('ProdPlat/ajax_test_div.html', dict)

    return render(request, 'ProdPlat/ajax_test.html', {'h2text': h2text})
```

And finally my Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    console.log('Button Clicked!');
    var text = $('h1').text()
    console.log('h1 text = ' + text);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : "/ProdPlat/Ajax_Test/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'text' : text,
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('data = ' + data);
            console.log('data.h2text = ' + data.h2text);
            $('#update_div').load(' #update_div')
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            console.log('Failed!');
            console.log('data = ' + data);
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: "I don't know if it's my Django return function or my Ajax function." You should be able to figure this out rather quickly with some basic debugging. As a first step, are your `console.log`s running as expected?

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks for your response! I am using the console.log to make sure I can get the h2text back from the view. When I return a JsonResponse, I can get the var for h2text to return to Ajax, but I don't know how to load the div afterward. I've read that you use the load function like so:  $('#update_div').load(' #update_div'), but that doesn't change the h2text.

Comment: OK cool - so it sounds like it's a javascript problem, not a django problem. That's good to know! I would recommend creating a _new_ question that is focused on how to update the contents of a div with javascript or jquery. The more focused and specific you can make your question, the more likely you are to get good responses. I actually don't think `.load()` is the right method, but I'm not a jquery expert.